# What is the correct way to use imported props in Vue 3 Typescript

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-sfc

What is the correct way to share props in vue 3 setup script

Im using the following right now:

```
// sharedProps.ts
import { ComponentObjectPropsOptions } from 'vue';

const sharedProps: ComponentObjectPropsOptions = {
  modelValue: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
  },
  id: {
    type: String,
    default: null,
  },
};
export default sharedProps;
```

And for the component

```
// Some component
<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineEmits, defineProps, ref } from 'vue';
import sharedProps from '@/props/sharedProps';

const props = defineProps({
  ...sharedProps,
  label: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
  },
});

...
</script>
```

And this works fine - But it seems that Rollup, VueDX etc. is not too happy about it. And it is not a type that is found in the documentation.
So what is the correct typing for shared props or way to share props?

Example of error msg when running Rollup

```
Default export of the module has or is using private name 'PropOptions'
```